# What underlayment material is this? Is it safe?

Tags: asbestos, demolition, underlayment

This underlayerment was found in a bathroom. It was under a cement layer with tiles on top. The house was constructed in the late 1980s.

What material is this underlayerment made of? Is it safe to handle?

[image]

Comment: Looks like chopped fiber glass reinforced plastic.  Late 1980's is awfully late for asbestos to be in use in most countries.

Comment: Agreed - that's far too coarse to be asbestos, as well.

Comment: I agree with Ecnerwal.  is this in a shower stall? Fiberglass pans are sometimes used I have seen them used with nothing on top and tiled over Yours looks like it was not coated thus made for tile.

Comment: Thanks for the all the help guys! Yes the layer is in a shower area